# SQL: possible pitfals with whitelist tables for a shared types table?

Tags: mysql, sql, design-patterns, anti-patterns

We've got an `association_types` table (MySQL) which is to be leveraged by all our "core entities" (people, companies, products).

Here's a truncated example:

```
CREATE TABLE association_types (`id` int, `type` varchar(24));  
INSERT INTO association_types (`id`, `type`) VALUES
    (1, 'parent'),
    (2, 'child'),
    (3, 'founder'),
    (4, 'employee'),
    (5, 'upgrade'),
    (6, 'downgrade');
```

Having one shared "types" table seems to make sense because there are association-types which apply to several entity types. For an example, let's look at parent/child.
Those can clearly apply to people, but are also used for companies (subsidiaries <-> holding companies), so maintaining separate association types tables seems like it could turn into a real headache pretty quickly.

The hitch with this structure is that when we use that table to populate some pull-down menus in the UI, it'll be a mess. It'd be ugly, and would provide non-applicable options.

The current plan is to have a simple whitelist table for each of our core entities to specify which assoc types apply to that data. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE person_association_whitelist (`association_type_id` int);  
INSERT INTO person_association_whitelist (`association_type_id`) VALUES
    (1),
    (2);

CREATE TABLE company_association_whitelist (`association_type_id` int); 
INSERT INTO company_association_whitelist (`association_type_id`) VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4);

CREATE TABLE product_association_whitelist (`association_type_id` int); 
INSERT INTO product_association_whitelist (`association_type_id`) VALUES
    (5),
    (6);
```

Is there an existing name for this pattern (or anti-pattern)?
Are there any pitfalls or gotchya's I should be aware of?
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Might be simpler to have a single whitelist table and add 'associated_to' or something to that extent (this way you simply add a where clause instead of selecting a separate table).  Is the 'whitelist' table entirely for drop down list population?

Comment: Twelfth As of now, it seems like the main use case will be "qualification". While the primary use case I have in my head right now is the drop down menus, this data will all be behind a webservices api, so technically, it'll be used for validation. Did you have any other (possibly better) ideas?